# SharePoint Framework Extensions invalid application package

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, deploy, spfx-extensions

I'm learning how to make a SharePoint Framework Extensions Apps. I made an app which is the same like in tutorial: [Deploy your extension to SharePoint (Hello world part 3)](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/extensions/get-started/serving-your-extension-from-sharepoint). Unfortunately i can't deploy apps which are SP Extensions. I even tried to upload a template app. Every time i have message:
 "The requested operation is part of an experimental feature that is not supported in the current environment."

I tried with webpart apps and everything works.

[image: App_Catalog]

Comment: What is the status now ? I have the header working when using debug url, then the app package deployed on first release / dev tenants do not show my header

Comment: For me, still doesn't work but probably because I don't have Developer Tenants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPFx extensions will work only on Developer Tenants.

If your tenant is on First release or General Availabilty(which looks like your tenant from the current error message) , it will not work.

To create a developer tenant, you can use either of the below 2 links:

1) https://demos.microsoft.com/Login

2) https://dev.office.com/devprogram

Reference - [SPFx extensions overview](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions)